# Process Start command prompt with /Y switch

Tags: vb.net

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", " /k  start SMC -disable -ntp /y ")
```

The following code does not work, it seems that the Y switch is being bypass.

If I were to open command prompt and key in the following, it work.

Comment: the option '/y' is it for CMD or SMC ?

Comment: Available command line options are [listed here](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH103048.html).  No mention of a /y option.  Use superuser.com or call Symantec support if you think it should work anyway.

Comment: hi the /y switch is yo answer yes or no to enable / disable ntp from smc

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
startInfo.FileName = "Firefox.exe"
startInfo.Arguments = "http://www.google.com"
Process.Start(startInfo)
```

Comment: What difference does this make? You never even included the `/Y` switch which we don't know if it's for SMC or CMD.